# Assigning a student to a teacher

Tags: entities

I've looked around for a couple hours but am not sure the best way to do what I need.

I need to set up a student teacher relationship so that when a student logs in on some pages viewed by the student the teachers picture and information will show up.

For example: the student logs in and is taken to the members area. Then the student clicks on lessons then on week 1 lesson 2. When the page for lesson 2 comes up it would have in the corner a picture of the teacher they are assigned to along with the teachers name, contact information...

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module to implement this. It depends on how teachers are assigned. Are teachers assigned to students ? or lessons ? based on this you can create a relation using the UI and assign teachers. For displaying information relation module integrates well with views, rules, cck and is very easy to create one.

I also used the module in my project where communities can have objectives and goals. I use the relation module to create relations and use the views to display the connections from the community.

I would also recommend you to watch [relation tutorial](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-the-relation-module) if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: Students are assigned to teachers. So one teacher might have 30 students assigned to them. Then each of the 30 students would see the teachers info but they don't see the other students.

Comment: yup that would work perfectly with the relations module. watch the tutorials to learn about how to create relations and display them using views.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably accomplish that by using simple [blocks](http://drupal.org/documentation/blocks).

You can edit your templates to show whatever blocks you want to, according to the node associated to the logged user, that being the professor to the student.

Not too hard I guess, and I hope that my answer can put you in the right track.